# How do you add class to parent :header only in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, filter

I need to change the css of the header using jQuery.

```
<main>
  <section>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>Work</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="row" id="work-page-body">
```

How do I do this using jQuery? Note: Cannot add id or class on them.

I tried:

```
$("#work-page-body").parent().addClass("work-page-header").filter(":header");
```

But not luck.

Comment: `$("#work-page-body").parent().find("header").addClass("work-page-header");`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `:header` selector, also note that `filter()` in this instance wouldn't retrieve the element you're looking for. Instead, use `find('header')`:

```
$("#work-page-body").parent().addClass("work-page-header").find("header");
```

If you're trying to add the `work-page-header` to the `header` element, you just need to reorder the method calls, like this:

```
$("#work-page-body").parent().find("header").addClass("work-page-header");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/u1w8tvs8/1)

Comment: My impression was that `work-page-header` should be added as a class on the header, but maybe I interpreted that incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided the header is not a parent of the div you are selecting therefore the parent function will not work. 
With your restrictions of not being able to add class or id to the div, your best bet may be to use the pre function. As shown below

```
$("#work-page-body").prev("header")
```

This would only work if you are certain that the head will aways be grouped with that div.